# Generate excel charts using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, excel, csv, charts

What I have to do: to generate excel files using JavaScript, filled with data and based on that data, a chart (for, let's say first 10 results).

The data part was solved. Is there a way to use pure JavaScript for adding charts (also in the excel file) using that data?

Comment: http://www.flotcharts.org/

Comment: Is there a specific problem you're having? Can you share what you've tried so far?

Comment: I need to add the chart in the excel file.. No code tried so far, I was searching and the only result I've got was the xlsx-chart. But I was wondering if there is another way to use pure JavaScript.

Comment: In what environment are you running this JavaScript (node.js? browser? something else?)? How are you already interacting with the Excel file? Are you generating the Excel file completely in JavaScript? This needs to be narrowed down in order to be really answerable without allowing for way too many possible interpretations.

Answer (score 2):

I think I may know a tool that could do exactly what you need. Here is a simple example.

[image]

There is a Excel add-in called Funfun, this add-in allows you to write and run JavaScript code directly in Excel as you could see in the picture. So instead of generating a Excel file using JavaScript, you could just type your data into Excel and write some code to make a chart using those data. In this example, I used HighCharts.js to make this chart.

One thing you need to notice is that you need to write a configuration in order to use in **shortIO** file. But it is really simple since it just define the area on the spreadsheet in which the data should be read. In this example, the configuration is just one line of code

```
 {
    "data": "=A1:B9"
 }
```

You also have another option, the Funfun also has an online editor, it's just like any other playground that might have used. But it is a bit special that it also has a sheet built into the online editor.(as shown in the pic below) You could also click the link below to check the Funfun online editor.

https://www.funfun.io/1/#/edit/5a4e478f1010eb73fe125cb2

[image]

Therefore, you could also test your code with your data in the online editor. Once you are satisfied with you result, you could just use the the link of the online editor to load all you code and data into Excel. But of course, first you need to add the Funfun add-in into your Excel by **Insert - Office Add-ins**. Here are some screenshots showing how you load the example into you Excel.

[image]

[image]

***Disclosure: I'm a developer of Funfun***

Comment: Very inappropriate answer. Nothing but the advertising of the product...

Comment: Just Advertising not much

Answer (score 0):

Well you can easly do charts with `char.js` libarary. It plays with your data and a Html5 canvas, here is the link:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/chart.js

Hope it's what you are searching.

Comment: Sorry, now I see that I've missed few details when asking. The chart should be added to the excel file too.